# Analysis and spelling correction of SMS text using python

Tags: python, text-analysis

For example, I have a sentence:

> hav bin reali happy since tlkin 2 u

With a python script, I want to edit above line so that it becomes:

> have been really happy since talking to you[sic]

How can I read each and every character and either replace or edit, or remove letter from words?
And can I/must I store the whole correct sentence in a different variable?

Comment: Can you reword this question so that it gets to the meat of it, either reading SMSes, or iterating through each character in a string? We don't need the preamble in order to help you solve the question

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, both i have to do. firstly i have to read all words of a sentence and check whether words are present in english dictionary or not. If not then edit or replace those words with the actual words of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
replacements = {
  'hav': 'have',
  'bin': 'been',
  'reali': 'really',
  'u': 'you',
  'tlkin': 'talking',
  '2': 'to'
}

sms = 'hav bin reali happy since tlkin 2 u'

original = ' '.join([replacements.get(w, w) for w in sms.split()])
print(original)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, sorry i forgot to mention there actually i just gave an example of a sentence. what if i have multiple sentences like this(SMS text). how will i manage the dictionary. no any sequence are there.

Comment: I know that this is an example. SO is not a code writing service!! you show us what u hv done so far so that we can help

Comment: Basically i am doing sentiment analysis using nltk, so for that i have to convert sms text sentence to english sentence so that i can generate unigram, bigrams and trigrams and match with my en_us english dictionary(positive words, negative words)